# Alternative to atof() function to differenciate input 0 with failure

Tags: c, floating-point, atof

I created a function to validate the input of real numbers . It is working well , but as the `atof()` function returns `0` upon failure, it is not possible to enter `0` as an input value. Anyone can give help to solve this?

```
float validate_float()
{
    float num;
    char str[8];
    do
    {
        printf("enter a float number:");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(str);
        num=atof(str);
    }
    while(num==0);
    return num;
}
```

Comment: So your question is what should you do to circumvent this limitation of `atof`?

Comment: I would suggest putting the `while (num == 0);` on the same line as the closing brace `}` as what you have here confuses into thinking you have a stray `while` running an infinite loop

Comment: yes :). I have a variable that should only accept float values between -10 and 15, inclusive the 0.
But I wanted to validate the data input, so that the user enter a letter the program not crashes.

Comment: Thank you : )! I found this function, and works fine to :).
int isfloat( char *str )
{
    double num;
    return sscanf(str, "%f", &num);
}

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that's a limitation for `atof()`.

You can make use of [`strtof()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtof)/[`strtod()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod) instead.

**Syantax:**

```
double strtod(const char *nptr, char **endptr);
float strtof(const char *nptr, char **endptr);
```

Note: To differenciate between an *actual input* `0` and a *no conversion* `0`, you need to check the `endptr`.

---

Now that said, as also mentioned by others,

- Do not use `fflush(stdin)`. It  invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
- Never use `gets()`, it suffers from possible buffer overflow. Use [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is a well-known limitation of `atof` as standardized. To circumvent this limitation, use `strtod` instead and pass a non-null pointer for the second argument.

From the man page on my system:

> double
>        strtod(const char *restrict nptr, char **restrict endptr);
>
> …
>
> If endptr is not NULL, a pointer to the character after the last character
>        used in the conversion is stored in the location referenced by endptr.
>
> If no conversion is performed, zero is returned and the value of nptr is
>        stored in the location referenced by endptr.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not `fflush()` `stdin` it's undefined behavior.
2. It's simple, just use this

   ```
   int isfloat(const char *value)
    {
       char *endptr;
       float num; 
       num = strtof(str, &endptr);
       if (*endptr != '\0')
           return 0;
       return 1;
    }
   ```